# How to query and receive as a result this kind of table?

Tags: sql-server, ascii, rtf

ASCII-RTF Character Chart
Table 4-1 shows the main printable characters you can access in RTF, as defined by the ANSI character set (also known as Code Page 1252, which is basically Latin-1 with some characters added between 128 and 159). Accessing Unicode characters is explained in the Character Formatting section of Chapter 1.

Note that while RTF escapes (\'xx) are valid for all characters, the only characters that have to be escaped are these three characters: {, }, and \, plus all the characters over code 127.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/rtf-pocket-guide/9781449302047/ch04.html

I have tried something like this

```
You can materialize a table with the ASCII codes or create one dynamically in a query. But be aware that only the code points 0-127 are ASCII characters. Characters in the range 128-255 are determined by the character code page (collation in SQL Server):

WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS id FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
SELECT 
    id
    , CHAR(id) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS CP1252_Char
    , CHAR(id) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CI_AS AS CP437_Char
FROM t256;
```

But it has an empty records in comparison with RTF-ASCII table provided by url above.

Comment: Which rows have empty records?  It seems to be well populated when I run it.

Comment: My query returns many records like this from 184 to 256: ? ?

Comment: May be need NCHAR() instead of CHAR()?

Comment: I've had to add an answer (which is not really an answer) to get the table to display.

Comment: You shouldn't need `NCHAR()` as ASCII is single byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had to add this as an answer because the table below will not fit into a comment.

For those rows, I get this:

```
+-----+-------------+------------+
| id  | CP1252_Char | CP437_Char |
+-----+-------------+------------+
| 184 | ¸           | ,          |
| 185 | ¹           | 1          |
| 186 | º           | º          |
| 187 | »           | »          |
| 188 | ¼           | ¼          |
| 189 | ½           | ½          |
| 190 | ¾           | _          |
| 191 | ¿           | ¿          |
| 192 | À           | A          |
| 193 | Á           | A          |
| 194 | Â           | A          |
| 195 | Ã           | A          |
| 196 | Ä           | Ä          |
| 197 | Å           | Å          |
| 198 | Æ           | Æ          |
| 199 | Ç           | Ç          |
| 200 | È           | E          |
| 201 | É           | É          |
| 202 | Ê           | E          |
| 203 | Ë           | E          |
| 204 | Ì           | I          |
| 205 | Í           | I          |
| 206 | Î           | I          |
| 207 | Ï           | I          |
| 208 | Ð           | D          |
| 209 | Ñ           | Ñ          |
| 210 | Ò           | O          |
| 211 | Ó           | O          |
| 212 | Ô           | O          |
| 213 | Õ           | O          |
| 214 | Ö           | Ö          |
| 215 | ×           | x          |
| 216 | Ø           | O          |
| 217 | Ù           | U          |
| 218 | Ú           | U          |
| 219 | Û           | U          |
| 220 | Ü           | Ü          |
| 221 | Ý           | Y          |
| 222 | Þ           | _          |
| 223 | ß           | ß          |
| 224 | à           | à          |
| 225 | á           | á          |
| 226 | â           | â          |
| 227 | ã           | a          |
| 228 | ä           | ä          |
| 229 | å           | å          |
| 230 | æ           | æ          |
| 231 | ç           | ç          |
| 232 | è           | è          |
| 233 | é           | é          |
| 234 | ê           | ê          |
| 235 | ë           | ë          |
| 236 | ì           | ì          |
| 237 | í           | í          |
| 238 | î           | î          |
| 239 | ï           | ï          |
| 240 | ð           | d          |
| 241 | ñ           | ñ          |
| 242 | ò           | ò          |
| 243 | ó           | ó          |
| 244 | ô           | ô          |
| 245 | õ           | o          |
| 246 | ö           | ö          |
| 247 | ÷           | ÷          |
| 248 | ø           | o          |
| 249 | ù           | ù          |
| 250 | ú           | ú          |
| 251 | û           | û          |
| 252 | ü           | ü          |
| 253 | ý           | y          |
| 254 | þ           | _          |
| 255 | ÿ           | ÿ          |
+-----+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: Ok, probably it is SSMS client side results visualization problem

Comment: Possibly, I'm using 2012 Management Studio connected to a 2014 back-end, not sure if it's relevant though.